How to determine from the lspci output how cards and how many ports are on a card?
I need to write a script to count how many 2 or 4 port HBA cards we have in each of our servers.
I'm running lspci on each of the servers, however, none of the documents I've read so far is telling me how to determine the number of cards and number of ports that are on each card.
This is some example output that I got back.  I've removed some lines so the output isn't as long.
# lspci | grep -i -E "fibre | ethernet"
5e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
5e:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
5f:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
5f:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
b0:00.0 Fibre Channel: Emulex Corporation LPe31000/LPe32000 Series 16Gb/32Gb Fibre Channel Adapter (rev 01)
b0:00.1 Fibre Channel: Emulex Corporation LPe31000/LPe32000 Series 16Gb/32Gb Fibre Channel Adapter (rev 01)
d8:00.0 Ethernet controller: QLogic Corp. FastLinQ QL41000 Series 10/25/40/50GbE Controller (rev 02)
d8:00.1 Ethernet controller: QLogic Corp. FastLinQ QL41000 Series 10/25/40/50GbE Controller (rev 02)
d8:00.2 Ethernet controller: QLogic Corp. FastLinQ QL41000 Series 10/25/40/50GbE Controller (rev 02)
d8:00.3 Ethernet controller: QLogic Corp. FastLinQ QL41000 Series 10/25/40/50GbE Controller (rev 02)

So looking at these output, can I assume that each bus number (e.g. 5e, 5f, d8, etc) is a separate card?  Can I also assume each function number for each bus:device pair is a port on that card?
e.g. 5e:00.0, 5e:00.1, 5e:00.2, 5e:00.3
So the Qlogic card is a 4 port card?
and e.g. 5e:00.0, 5e:00.1
And there are 2 Mellanox cards where each is a 2 port card?

Does lscpi -vv help?

@icarus, thanks, it sort of helps.  I can manually read the output to get what I need but I don't think I can write a script to do so.  At least some of the information is either in a non-deterministic spot, meaning depending on the card/company, the port info is 3, 6, 10, or 20 lines down.  The other issue is sometimes it says 2-port, dual port, 4-port, quad port which also isn't standard so I can't scrape for this information.  If there isn't a command that gives it to me easily, I guess this is better than nothing but I was hoping there's a command that gives me this info straight up.

lspci does have some options to output structured data, which you might be able to parse with say jq. A different approach might be to parse the output of the ip link command. You might add some information on why you want this information, for example why do you care if it is 1 4-port card or 2 2-port cards?

Thanks, ip link wouldn't work b/c I have fibre channel cards which don't seem to appear in the output there.

@icarus, if you make your comment into an answer, I can upvote it.  I wrote a script to parse/scrape the output to possibly figure out how many ports the card has.

I would expect that's four distinct cards there, but I could be wrong. If you can look physically at one of the servers, that might help figuring out how the cards correspond to the lspci output

lspci has a number of options which might help. In particular -vv outputs more information, and -vmm produces machine readable information.
